# Custom UITableViewCell, GetCell throws UnknownNSKeyException

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xib, iboutlet

I have created a custom `UITableViewController`, Cell and Source in my project. The Controller and the Cell were originally created as an iPhone UIViewController template so that I got the partial class paired with the XIB file. I have the same setup already working with another table and I have followed the same process (I think) to create this one which is why I have no idea why I'm getting this error.

This is my `GetCell` in the `TableViewSource` class

```cs
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UItableView tv, NSIndexPath path)
{
    MyCell oCell;
    NSArray oViews;
    //
    oCell = tv.DequeueReusableCell ("MyCell") as MyCell;
    //
    if (oCell == null)
    {
        oViews = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("MyCell", tv, null);
        oCell = Runtime.GetNSObject (oViews.ValueAt (0)) as MyCell;
    }
    //
    oCell.UpdateWithData (MyDataCollection[path.Row]);
    //
    return oCell;
}
```

I get the exception on the line where it tries to load the nib:

> Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason:
>   [ setValue:forUnidentifiedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key lbl_address.

I'm thinking that this refers to a problem in IB where I have created the cell interface as `lbl_address` is a UILabel that is inside the `UITableViewCell`. I'm trying to play around with some things in IB but it can be pretty infuriating if you don't do it correctly first time round. Hopefully someone will recognise this error and set me straight.

**EDIT**

In the absence of finding an answer to this I have chosen to avoid loading from the nib and have made the following changes to my code:

New `Get Cell` method in `MyTableViewSource`

```cs
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv, NSIndexPath path)
{
    MyCell oCell;
    //
    oCell = tv.DequeueReusableCell ("MyCell") as MyCell;
    //
    if (oCell == null)
        oCell = new MyCell ("MyCell");
    //
    oCell.UpdateWithData (MyDataCollection[path.Row]);
    //
    return oCell;
}
```

New constructor for `MyCell`

```cs
public MyCell (string sIdentifier)
    : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, sIdentifier)
{
    // Set up the contents of the cell in the absence of loading from the nib
    txt_name = new UILabel ()
    {
        Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (15),
        TextColor = UIColor.LightGray
    };
    img_profile = new UIImageView ();
    //
    // Make sure to add the controls to the content view!
    ContentView.Add (txt_name);
    ContentView.Add (img_profile);
}
```

Hope this helps someone out there :)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to an element that has been removed but a previous connection outlet in the xib still remains valid.

I would try the following steps.

Open the xib. Right click on the cell. If you see a yellow warning near that key name, remove it (x button).

Let me know if this fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry for long delay in answering! Following what you said I could not find any warnings in the xib or any other outlets in there. I found that I had to avoid loading from the nib in this case, simply creating a constructor for the cell that used the base `UITableViewCell` constructor (`UITableViewCellType`, `string`).